# Como eliminar FOREIGN KEY Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una consulta y necesito eliminar una tabla pero como tiene FOREIGN KEY no me deja no hay ningunan sentencia sql que elimine todas sus foreign key

```
DROP TABLE [DEMO].[dbo].[VLD_ARTICULOSUSUARIO]

SELECT * INTO [DEMO].[dbo].[VLD__ARTICULOSUSUARIO] 
FROM
[miproyecto\MSSQLSERVER2017].[sql].[dbo].[VLD_ARTICULOSUSUARIO]
```

Answer (score 2):

Precisamente las constraint se crean para eso. Y lo que planteas es un poco "atroz". No obstante como por el nombre de las bases de datos, esta claro, que son de desarrollo para probar cosas, siempre puedes utilizar una query dinámica.

```
DECLARE @ConstraintName SYSNAME;
DECLARE @SQL Nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE cCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Constraint_Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T
WHERE T.Table_Name = 'VLD_ARTICULOSUSUARIO';

OPEN cCursor
FETCH cCursor INTO @ConstraintName
While (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN
    
    Set @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE VLD_ARTICULOSUSUARIO
                DROP CONSTRAINT '+@ConstraintName+';';
    EXEC sp_executeSql @SQL;

FETCH cCursor INTO @ConstraintName
END
CLOSE cCursor
DEALLOCATE cCursor
```

Obtienes de INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Table_Constraints todas las que están disponibles para tu tabla, y realizas un alter table, sobre ese nombre.

Quizá cuando existen planteamientos de este tipo, es más fácil delegar, la gestión de la eliminación y de las actualizaciones a la propia base de datos, creando las restricciones con ON UPDATE y ON DELETE y así no quedan registros huérfanos.

[Eliminar en cascada](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/eliminar-en-cascada-y-actualizar-cascada-en-la-clave-externa-de-sql-server/)

[InformationSchema Table Constraints](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/table-constraints-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)